# SDWebImage into NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, sdwebimage

How can I add 3 imageviews using SDWebImage into NSArray?

I have my images in this form:

```
[self.imageView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"image1"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

[self.imageView2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"image2"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

[self.imageView3 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"image3"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Your 2nd piece of codes contain invalid syntax. Double check. By the way, "does not work" is not an issue description

Comment: Could you give me some hint, where the invalid syntax is?

Comment: Xcode didn't tell you? **check the brackets**.

Comment: Ops, its invalid NSArray which I didn`t want to post, sorry. My misstake

Answer (score 1):

`SDWebImage` has another method with the completion block. Use that method

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"image1"]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                          //completion code here ...

                          [self.animationArray addObject:image]; // animationArray is an array property
                      }];
```

Add the `image` to the `animationArray` from the completion block

Comment: And if I want to add 3 different images with different URLs, I have to add the three time into block with this method? Isn`t there any other way?

Comment: In SDWebImage no other way. otherwise you could use your own method

Answer (score -1):

If adding the 3 imageViews to your array is what you are aiming at then your second piece of code should be

```
  NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.imageView1, self.imageView2, self.imageView3, nil];
```

Although using the completion block is being suggested in the answer and maybe the best practice, this approach should also should manage fine considering that your imageWithURL call from SDWebImage will handle the network operation and update the objects when it receives the image.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: I have added further detail, does the explanation suffice now?

Comment: It does but it doesn`t work well. I did it like this and getting error.